# How can I create a shortcut to a printer's queue on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, queue

How can I create a desktop shortcut to a printer's queue on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit?

Thanks.

For any future searchers, what worked for me is a little different from what's in the accepted answer, so I added it in the comments for the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open Devices and Printers, Right-click the printer, and click "Create shortcut".

It will put the shortcut on your desktop and you can then move it wherever you want.

You can see the one I created, and opened by clicking the shortcut to the right in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I was just coming to delete this question.  I did it by dragging the See What's Printing button to the desktop.  When I did what you were saying, the shortcut opened printer's main page and I still had to click on "See what's printing" or "Printer:ready" to see the queue.  But, thanks just the same.