# Printer queue quick launch

Tags: windows-10, printer, cmd.exe, hotkeys

Can I open printer queue from keyboard? Or maybe programmatically (PS/CMD) so that I can access it from console quickly?

I saw [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/317863/how-can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-a-printers-queue-on-windows-7) but placing queue on the desktop seems inelegant solution for me.

Comment: Any shortcut can had a keyboard hotkey added to it, and then that keyboard hotkey will open the shortcutted item.

Comment: Yep, I knew that, but I thought maybe there is native shortcut I am missing)

Comment: Though, command will be helpful too, as I found only [flushing command](https://superuser.com/questions/431839/how-to-flush-printer-queue-via-command-line-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there's a good chance there are multiple queues for multiple printers, it makes no sense for Microsoft to create a default "Open Printer Queue" keyboard shortcut.

However, you can call the queue for a specific printer from the command line.

You'll need to know the specific name of the printer you are trying to view. If it is a network printer the name will be the full network path: "\servername\printershare"

And then you put it together:

```
rundll32.exe printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /o /n "printername"
```

If you've entered the printer name correctly, the print queue dialog will open.

Comment: Spectacular! Exactly what I need